# How do I write a modem for DireWolf?

Tags: packet, software-development, modem, direwolf, tnc

I was looking at the selection of modem bauds for DireWolf and it seems the highest baud modem is 9600 baud, and I am using a sound card that can reach 48 khz. Is there any way that I can write a modem for DireWolf to utilize the 48 khz capabilities of the sound card?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, direwolf already supports higher data rates since 2017; it will use the G3RUH modem for a speed of 9600 *or higher*. As shipped it can be configured up to 40000 bps.

But it's a mistake to think that 9600bps isn't making use of a 48kHz sample rate. The author has [done some testing](https://github.com/wb2osz/direwolf/blob/master/doc/Going-beyond-9600-baud.pdf) which shows that 9600bps is about the highest rate that works reliably with 48KHz (and in fact it benefits slightly from 96kHz); 14.4kbps and 19.2kbps require 96kHz sampling to work respectably, and higher rates require 192kHz.

You can, of course, attempt to write your own modem that performs better; I can't provide much advice on how to do it, except... do it. Look at `demod_afsk.c` (300 and 1200), `demod_psk.c` (2400 and 4800), and `demod_9600.c` (9600+), make your own with a corresponding set of public functions, wire it into `demod.c` and `config.c`, and give it a try. The included `gen_packets` and `atest` utilities will be helpful for testing.